# Xamarin code stops functioning

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin mobile program with portable library which I am running on Android.

I run the following piece of code which usually operates fine, but sometimes it seems to 'jam' up and it gets to the line which executes a query to the remote odata endpoint and then simply stops.  It doesn't raise and error, or pass through the error capture points and all code after this is not implemented in the call chain.  It simply stops operating.  Once it does this once - it continues to do this forever.  I have checked the credentials at entry - all fine.

The app continues on as if nothing has happened - it's just skipped whole swathes of code in doing so.  no memory warnings given either.

Any ideas appreciated.

```
       public async Task<bool> canSetLoggedInPersonWithCredentials_async(System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        if (credentials == null) return false;
        mRemoteEntities.Credentials = credentials;

        DataServiceQuery<Person> query = (DataServiceQuery<Person>)mRemoteEntities.People.Where(c => c.UserName == credentials.UserName );
        TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Person>> tf = new TaskFactory< IEnumerable<Person>>();
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Person> personLoggedIn = await tf.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute(null, null),
                                       iar => query.EndExecute(iar)); ** STOPS HERE **

            IList<Person> listOfPeople = personLoggedIn.ToList();
            int numberOfPeople = listOfPeople.Count;
            if (numberOfPeople == 0) return false;
            if (numberOfPeople > 1)
            {
                //Error - this should never happen and represents an integrity error in the database
               SystemLogManager.AddErrorToLog(mLocalDataConnection, SystemLogLocation.Library, "Whilst logging in: More than 1 person with the same username", false);

            }
            mLoggedInUser = listOfPeople.ElementAt(0);
           SystemLogManager.addCommentToLog(mLocalDataConnection, SystemLogLocation.Library, "Login was successful");
            return true;

        }
        catch (DataServiceQueryException dsqEx)
        {
            if (dsqEx.InnerException is DataServiceClientException  )
            {
                DataServiceClientException inner =( DataServiceClientException) dsqEx.InnerException;
                if (inner.StatusCode == 401)
                {
                    SystemLogManager.AddErrorToLog(mLocalDataConnection, SystemLogLocation.Library, " Invalid Login credentials" + inner.StatusCode, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    SystemLogManager.AddErrorToLog(mLocalDataConnection, SystemLogLocation.Library, "Login Error: DataServiceClientExceptionData Message: " + inner.Message + " and code " + inner.StatusCode, false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SystemLogManager.AddErrorToLog(mLocalDataConnection, SystemLogLocation.Library, "Login Error: DataServiceQueryException Message: " + dsqEx.Message , false);
            }
            return false;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SystemLogManager.AddErrorToLog(mLocalDataConnection, SystemLogLocation.Library, "Login Error: Unknown Exception Message: " + ex.Message, false);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might help if you put a comment in your code saying stops here.  Also I would run a network tool to capture traffic to see whether the call is being made and a response is being received

Comment: thanks - have marked in where it stops.  The code disappears but it doesn't break, i.e. the code does a massive jump to the end of that thread and the mobile app continues on as usual after that waiting for the user to do something.  It's like someone lops off all the remaining code that has to run, without causing an exception